# SSIS Script Component errors sporadically with the same code

Tags: ssis, scripting

I have a SSIS `Data Flow Task` that takes CSV output (from a flat file connection) and passes that to a `Script Component`. When I run the task I get the following error:

> Script Component has encountered an exception in user code
>
> Project name: blahblahbla
>
> String was not recognized as valid DateTime

```
at System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles)
at ScriptMain.Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
at UserComponent.Input0_ProcessInput(Input0Buffer Buffer)
at UserComponent.ProcessInput(Int32 InputID, String InputName, PipelineBuffer Buffer, OutputNameMap OutputMap)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponent.ProcessInput(Int32 InputID, PipelineBuffer buffer)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponentHost.ProcessInput(Int32 inputID, PipelineBuffer buffer)
```

Which is interesting because I don't think there is a date column in the CSV, and I'm not using DateTime in this code at all.

When I go into the script and debug it, it runs smoothly. Then I take away the break point and it errors again. This seems to be some kind of race condition, which makes me worried about my other script components. This component was created via a copy paste - **could that effect anything?**

My user code from that function is here:

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    // Create a new row
    DataRow glRow = _data.NewRow();

    glRow["xx"] = Row.xx;
    glRow["xx"] = Row.xx;
    glRow["xx"] = Row.xx;
    glRow["xx"] = Row.xx;
    glRow["xx"] = ConvertToBool(Row.xx);
    glRow["xx"] = ConvertToBool(Row.xx);

    // Add row to _data
    _data.Rows.Add(glRow);

}
```

And the function is:

```
private object ConvertToBool(string obj)
{
    if (obj.Replace(" ", "") == "") return DBNull.Value;
    return (obj == "1") ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: After deleting and recreating the script component with an exact copy paste of the code, the problem went away. SSDT is so full of bugs it is truly unbelievable that Microsoft released it (I'm using 14.0.617)

Comment: SSDT has it's fair share of bugs but IMHO you'll only multiply them if you use the script component. As I mentioned in your other post, I avoid it if possible. If your package revolves around script tasks, the first thing to do is work out if it can be done in the database instead, If not, it's more reliable and maintainable to just build it in something native like a C# console app.

Comment: Thanks for that @Nick.McDermaid. I thought I was being all anti establishment by thinking that self-written code was a better option than SSIS in this case. The reason I'm using scripts is because I'm parsing a malformed CSV with about 40K rows and 113 columns. So far as I know there is no good way of processing such a CSV with anything EXCEPT scripts? because I have to import the CSV as a single column so far as I know...

Comment: There's a follow up question to this one here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/177143/which-is-quicker-in-ssis-uploading-to-a-database-via-sp-with-tvp-param-or-usin

Comment: It's tricky to troubleshoot these intermittent errors. Is there any date data types in the data being loaded? As in in the metadata that feeds into or out of the script component? I proabably can't help much with this - I'll just keep reiterating that I prefer T-SQL to C# ! :)