# Which is quicker in SSIS: uploading to a database via SP with TVP param, or using an OLE DB Destination?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm importing a (relatively) malformed CSV into SQL Server via SSIS. So far my workflow is:

1. Import CSV as one column
2. Use script component to clean up into 113 properly formed columns

Now I have a choice: I can configure the script component as either a 'transformation' or a 'destination' step. I have chosen 'destination', which involved:

1. Creating a DataTable
2. Then iterating through single column rows, splitting, and populating DataTable
3. Calling SP in SQL Server with DataTable as a param

I have found this works with a sample of the CSV, but have not been successful with the entire CSV. I suspect this is because I'm developing remotely and the 50mb + DataTable upload is causing the package to time out.

So my question is:

Would using the SSIS `OLE DB Destination` task be more reliable and faster in some way than what I'm currently doing?

Comment: My guess both methods will provide similar performance with attention to detail. In the case of the DataTable TVP, it is important to specify a MaxLength that matches the target table type column length for string columns, especially when a server side trace that captures RPC events is running. The default max length is -1 (2GB).

Comment: I've specified NVARCHAR(MAX) for all string types in the table-type. I could probably shorten that to NVARCHAR(250) or so and just truncate any longer values without anyone caring. What are the potential pitfalls of using NVARCHAR(MAX) in a TVP?

Comment: I would avoid nvarchar(MAX) in TVPs when possible. See http://www.dbdelta.com/sql-server-tvp-performance-gotchas/.

Comment: Thanks @DanGuzman. Looking at my code, I'm specifying the DataTable columns like so: `_data.Columns.Add("LineCode", typeof(string));`. And adding a C# `string` object to the cell for that column. So I'm not specifying a string length in the SSIS package. 

When the SP is called with a param (@param = _data), would the column definitions in the type have any effect on how the data is sent over the network?

Comment: No, difference on what's sent over the wire except for the column meta data preceding the rows. For non-MAX strings, you should specify the max length with code like `_data.Columns.Add("LineCode", typeof(string)).MaxLength = 250;`

Comment: ok. I think I would very seldom (or never) hit this point: `When the specified max length of variable length columns exceed the 8000 byte tipping point, SQL Server uses a different code path to allow for large object (LOB) values up to 2GB.`. So I don't think that my NVARCHAR(MAX) TVP typing has any effect on performance. (though I'll be sure to change it in the future!) Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Oops. Should have included this part: `SQL Server prepares to receive TVP data up to the max length specified by the client application rather than the defined size of the target table type column.`

Comment: I suggest you write one stored procedure that uses `BULK INSERT` to insert the entire file into a single column in a staging table then uses T-SQL to shred the data out in the way you want it. You can add columns to the staging table to help work through the data. This is a purely T-SQL approach. IMHO it's simpler and will likely run much faster than a row by row approach. No SSIS, no script tasks, no deployment etc. There are a few config items to sort out but this approach allows you to keep all of your code in one spot (i.e .in the actual database that you are importing into)

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - at the moment we have several databases that collectively have hundred SPs TVPs, functions, etc, which has resulted in very opaque data processing.  We are testing ways of improving maintainability and portability to different servers. SSIS looks promising because of the visual workflow.

Comment: Yes its fantastic for visual workflow and logical organisation of processing units. This can include, for example, the calling of stored procedures that do all your work. It's difficult to answer your original question without more details and an actual error message though.

Comment: yes. although instead of SPs, I'm just using SQL execution tasks - with all staging data loaded to actual tables that I delete from before and after. Thank you for all the feedback @Nick.McDermaid. I included an error message here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/177074/ssis-script-component-errors-sporadically-with-the-same-code. Is that what you mean? Otherwise let me know and I'll update my questions accordingly

Comment: The pattern I use is: 1. Truncate staging; 2. load data to staging with data flow; 3. Call stored procedure to process staging. These are all called from a SSIS package. You can see the high level workflow in the SSIS package. You can use multiple SSIS packages to split out units of work. .You can unit test each SP to make sure it works without opening SSIS. Lastly.. you avoid flaky and inefficient script tasks. I always leave staging tables populated between calls so that I can troubleshoot. I also include a `DateModified` in staging tables so I know when data was last imported.

Comment: This is not everyone's cup of tea. I just have an aversion to script tasks, and having to load a special tool like SSDT, along with the associated projects etc. just to process some data. If you have a mature team that prefers C# to T-SQL, scripts might be better from a maintenance perspective.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I like the idea of adding a date modified to the table. Do you use a trigger to create a date on entry? or do you insert with a date already